# cancel button on javascript dialog to stop a loop

Tags: javascript, html

Greeting. When I open the following in Internet Explorer 11, the game would not stop when I hit the cancel button. How I can press the cancel button and the game stops. The current behavior is it just keep looping even with cancel ??

```
var target;            
var guess_input_text;   
var guess_input;      
var finished = false;   
var guesses = 0;

function do_game() {
    var random_number = Math.random() * 100;
    var random_number_integer = Math.floor(random_number);
    target = random_number_integer;

    while (!finished) {
        guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of a number "+
                                  "in the range 1 to 100.\n\n"+
                                  "What is the number?");
        guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text);
        guesses += 1;   
        finished = check_guess();
    }
}

function check_guess() {
    if (isNaN(guess_input)) {
        alert("You have not entered a number.\n\n" +
              "Please enter a number in the range 1 to 100.");
        return false;
    }
    if ((guess_input < 1) || (guess_input > 100)) {
        alert("Please enter an integer number in the range 1 to 100.");
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input > target) {
        alert("Your number is too large!");
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input < target) {
        alert("Your number is too small!");
        return false;
    }
    alert("You got it! The number was " + target + 
          ".\n\nIt took you " + guesses + 
          " guesses to get the number!");
    return true;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you press the Cancel button on `prompt`'s prompt, it returns `null`. So

```
if (guess_input_text === null) {
    break;
}
```

...will exit the loop.

Note that on quite old browsers, it would return `""` rather than `null`. But anything vaguely modern (IE9+) should be fine.